# How do I run a java program from a different directory?

Tags: java, bash, scripting, cygwin

I have a java program that I would like to be able to run from anywhere on my machine.  I would like to run it from my Cygwin command prompt.  I've made scripts to call the java program.  I added the location of the java program to the classpath, and the scripts work when I run them from the java program's directory.  However, when I try to run from any other directory, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commandprogram/CommandProgram
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
CWD=`dirname "$0"`
java -cp "$CWD/classes;$CWD/lib/AJarFile.jar" commandprogram/CommandProgram
```

Changing the java line to the following:

```
java -cp "$CWD/classes;$CWD/classes/commandprogram;$CWD/lib/AJarFile.jar" CommandProgram
```

produces the same results.

Comment: could you post your script, that will give people a better idea on where to look at...

Comment: Don't you need to do java commandprogram/CommandProgram.class or java -jar commandprogram/CommandProgram.jar?

Comment: isnt' the path separator a colon (:) instead of the semicolon (;) you've used?

Comment: The path separator is a colon on *nix, semicolon on Windows.  I'm not sure which one you use in cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying just about everything I could think of, I echoed out the command and saw that there was mixing of Cygwin paths and Windows paths.  The solution was to change the script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
CWD=`dirname "$0"`
CWD=`cygpath -w "$CWD"`
java -cp "$CWD/classes;$CWD/lib/AJarFile.jar" commandprogram/CommandProgram
```

Then CWD changed to "C:\Program Files\..." instead of "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/..."

I had previously encountered this problem and solved it with the `cygpath -w` solution, but then changed my script slightly and didn't notice that the path problem came back.

Answer (score 30):

add your directory to classpath example:

```
java -classpath commandprogram CommandProgram
```

or

```
java -classpath directory_to_program Program
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a dot to separate packages, not a slash.

> java -cp "$CWD/classes;$CWD/lib/AJarFile.jar" commandprogram.CommandProgram

Comment: / works too.  Keep in mind that the script works when I'm in the directory with the scripts.

Answer (score -10):

The usual way of running a java file is to save it in the `Java/Bin` folder and Run `cmd`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin> javac filename.java && java classname
```

If you save the file in  different directory such as `D:`, you can use the following on the cmd prompt:

```
D:\Project java> set path=%path%;C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
```

Comment: Saving your java files or class files in the Java `bin` directory is, in fact, very unusual and should be avoided. The Java `bin` directory is for Java's own binary files and *nothing* else.