# how to execute cmd command using another program in java

Tags: java

I want to make a program that open another java programs.how can i run/execute the cmd command in compiling and running java programs.

for example c:\Users\Burnok> javac HelloWorld.java and 
            c:\Users\Burnok> java HelloWorld

how can i do that inside the java program? please help.

I tried this code but it compiled successfully but if i tried to run the HelloWorld.class it says that the could not find or load main class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class Test {

     private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(ins));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(name + " " + line);
            }
          }

      private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        pro.waitFor();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            runProcess("javac src/HelloWorld.java");
            runProcess("java src/HelloWorld");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

here is the error
java src/HelloWorld stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class src.HelloWorld

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program

Comment: i try that but if i tried to run the .class it says that could not find or load main class.

Comment: can you post exactly what you have tried?

Comment: see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: Have you checked where HelloWorld.class gets generated and where the current context is when you execute?  Is is possible the class file is inside the src directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are supposed to mention class path while running from another directory

syntax is `java -classpath directory_to_program Program`

```
try {
        runProcess("javac src/HelloWorld.java");
        runProcess("java -classpath src HelloWorld");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Read for more info [How do I run a java program from a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190018/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-a-different-directory)

Comment: Thanks it display hello world but i want to run just like the Test class that open another cmd

Comment: @user3276091 sorry can you explain 'that open another cmd' ?

Comment: @user3276091 sujithvm just fixed the bug, not introduced the new way to run, what's the problem then?

Comment: yeah but sorry but i want to open another cmd that display helloWorld

Comment: @user3276091 Do you another **window** with command line to be opened?

Comment: yes.can you please teach me. because i want to make a program that will open a java GUI window using that Test class.

Comment: In Windows, put "start" in front of the command. "start java -classpath src HelloWorld"