# Run a java program from anywhere

Tags: java, cmd, compilation, noclassdeffounderror

I am running a java program using a .bat file. It works well after double clicking direcctly on the .bat, that's not the problem.

What I want now, is to run that .bt file (and the java program by extends) from the cmd at first, and then to be able to compile it from any other machine.

I have followed at first the following answer : [How do I run a java program from a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190018/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-a-different-directory) , but it didn't work for me.

Here is my .bat file :

```
@echo on

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.;lib/console.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.13.jar;lib/prog1.jar;lib/prog1_newOption.jar;lib/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar;lib/RXTXcomm.jar;lib/trace.jar;lib/xercesImpl.jar;lib/xml-apis.jar

java -cp "$/prog1_newOption/src/main/Main" %UsersCommand%

pause
exit

%cmd%
```

Maybe have I to look for the main path in the .bat file and then parse it the the "java command programm" line?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You're running your program before you're compiling it, you should switch those two lines around

Comment: you don't really need a .bat file, you can make a jar executable

Comment: @Stultuske even if I want the user to choose options?

Comment: @Lino 
Like this : ' java -cp "$CLASSPATH 
java main.Main %UsersCommand%  ' ?

Comment: @Nour I can't try it out, but I expect it to work

Comment: @Lino, I have just try it now, it gives me the error of an unfoundable main class. That's the same error I had

Comment: @Nour nothing stops you from using properties files

Comment: @Stultuske, my cmd says that the request is non valid, and doesn't send any error. my request was a simple 'wmic datafile where Name= "file path" '. maybe I have an autorization problem?

I mean both my .bat and program are in the "user's folder"